# Import xgboost model into pyspark script directly from HDFS

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark, hdfs, xgboost

I try to load xgboost model in .dat format into pyspark script directly from HDFS.

I tried to use `SparkContext.addFile()`. But It's not working for me. Code:

```
model = sc.addFile("hdfs://namenode:8088/home/jup-user/testdb/scripts/titanic_pickle.dat")
print(type(model))
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/jup-user/testdb/scripts/loadhdfs.py", line 63, in 
>       model = sc.addFile("hdfs://namenode:8088/home/jup-user/testdb/scripts/titanic_pickle.dat")
>     File "/data_disk/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.15.1-1.cdh5.15.1.p0.4/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 787, in addFile
>     File "/data_disk/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.15.1-1.cdh5.15.1.p0.4/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in **call**
>     File "/data_disk/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.15.1-1.cdh5.15.1.p0.4/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
>     File "/data_disk/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.15.1-1.cdh5.15.1.p0.4/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
>   py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o51.addFile.

But if I load textfile from HDFS, using `SparkContext.textFile()` it's working:

```
textfile1 = sc.textFile("hdfs://namenode:8088/home/jup-user/testdb/scripts/data/clean_test.csv")
print(type(textfile1))
```

> class 'pyspark.rdd.RDD'

I tried to use SparkFiles and PyFiles but spark-submit can't understand HDFS (hdfs://) path. Pickle also can't understand HDFS path

I'll be glad to see all your suggestions about importing xgboost models (or files with any formats) into pyspark script.

BR,
Vladimir

Comment: What are your `spark-submit` arguments?

Comment: `spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --files hdfs://namenode:8088/home/jup-user/testdb/scripts/titanic_pickle.dat`

Comment: Can you try without addFile()?

Comment: Yes, I tried, and it's works. It's was problem with my cluster.